# Azure Search service with partitioned Document Db

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to Azure. I tried to create a Search service with index of Partitioned DocumentDb. So my documentdb have a partionkey and id. While adding that as my search service data source I am getting the following error :

**Error detecting index schema from source : "Message : {"Errors":The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey has fewer components than defined in the collection"}"**

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search doesn't currently support partitioned DocumentDB collections. However, we plan to add this support in the next few weeks. Please contact me at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain and I'll update you when it's available. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eugene, I still get this error. Has this been taken care of? I am able to add and retrieve records with partition key through code, but I get an error when I try to browse it in VS cloud explorer.

Comment: @Noor, sorry I'm not familiar with VS cloud explorer. I suggest that you post a separate question about that issue and tag it appropriately.